# Sufficient Condition for the Existence of Vertex Disjoint Shortest Paths

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G(V,E)$ be a symmetric connected graph with $n$ vertices and let $D\in\mathbb{N}_0^{n\times n}$ be the matrix containing as entries $d_{uv}$ the least number of edges on a path from $u$ to $v$.

For an easier formulation of the question let $\Pi_{uv}$ denote the set of vertices of the union of all the shortest paths between $u$ and $v$ and let further $\Pi_{uv}^i\subseteq\Pi_{uv}$ denote the set of vertices $\lbrace w\in V\ |\ d_{uw}=i\ \wedge\ d_{uw}+d_{wv}=d_{uv}\rbrace$ that is are on a shortest path from $u$ to $v$ at distance $i$ from $u$.

> **Question:**
>
> if $d_{rs} = d_{rt}$, is it true, that $$\mathrm{card}(\Pi_{rs}^i \cup \Pi_{rt}^i)\gt 1\ \quad\forall i\in\lbrace 1,\ \cdots,\ d_{rs}-1\rbrace$$
> is sufficient for the existence of an vertex-disjoint (w.r.t. the inner path-vertices) pair $\left([r,\ \cdots,\ s];\ [r,\ \cdots,\ t]\ \right)$ of shortest paths between $r$ and $s$, resp. between $r$ and $t$?

It is clear that $$\exists\ \forall i\in\lbrace 1,\ \cdots,\ d_{rs}-1\rbrace:\ \mathrm{card}(\Pi_{rs}^i \cup \Pi_{rt}^i)= 1$$ rules out the existence of such a pair.

Please note that it is essential for the question that the shortest distances between pairs of vertices are available from an inevitable calculation and the hope is that that allows for a more efficient decision about the existence of an edge-disjoint pair of paths than to resort to one of the diverse-routing algorithms from the survivable networks domain (I know of the book of Bhandari).